# How to create custom cropper for flutter apps?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and am trying to create a custom cropper in my flutter project. I tried implementing different approaches but nothing seems to work. So here in my code after I select the image I want to implement a simple cropper in the app. How do I do this?

```
Container(
                      height: 250,
                      width: 350,
                      child: image != null
? InteractiveViewer(
                              key: key,
                              transformationController:
                                  transformationController,
                              child: Image.file(
                                image!,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            )
: const SizedBox(
                              width: 350,
                              height: 250,
                            ),
                    ),
```

Tried using cropperx but it doesnt give the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
class CustomCropper extends StatefulWidget {final File image;
const CustomCropper({Key? key, required this.image}) : super(key: key);
@override
  State<CustomCropper> createState() => _CustomCropperState();
}
class _CustomCropperState extends State<CustomCropper> {
  late CroppedFile croppedFile;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    cropImage();
  }
Future<void> cropImage() async {
    final cropper = ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: widget.image.path,
      aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
      maxHeight: 500,
      maxWidth: 500,
    );
    croppedFile = await cropper.croppedFile;
    if (croppedFile != null) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (croppedFile == null) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      return Image.file(
        croppedFile.path,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      );
    }
  }
}
```